# How to use custom type-safe aggregator in Spark SQL

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset, apache-spark-2.0

The Spark documentation describes how to create both a [untyped user defined aggregate function](http://spark.apachecn.org/docs/en/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#untyped-user-defined-aggregate-functions) ([code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/udaf.scala)) (aka udaf) and a [strongly-typed aggregator](http://spark.apachecn.org/docs/en/2.2.0/sql-programming-guide.html#type-safe-user-defined-aggregate-functions) ([code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/Aggregator.scala)) (aka a subclass of `org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Aggregator`).

I know you can register a udaf for use in sql via `spark.udf.register("udafName", udafInstance)`, then use it like `spark.sql("SELECT udafName(V) as aggV FROM data")`.

Is there a way to use an aggregator in sql too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really `Aggregator` API is designed specifically with "strongly" typed `Datasets` in mind. You'll notice, that it doesn't take `Columns` but always operates on whole record objects.

This doesn't really fit into SQL processing model:

- In SQL you always operate on `Dataset[Row]`. Not much use for `Aggregator`.
- Operations are applied on columns while `Aggregator` takes a complete `Row`.

For use with SQL API you can create [`UserDefinedAggregateFunction`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction) which can be registered using [standard methods](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.UDFRegistration@register(name:String,udaf:org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction):org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction).

Comment: That's what I was thinking, but I was hoping there was a way for us to re-use our aggregators in some sql code without having to write UDAF.  Thanks for the response.